# Azure B2C - Facebook Signup asks for Profile picture instead of email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I have a B2C custom policy that uses Facebook as an IDP.  My policy asks FB for name, email etc.  However, when a user signs up throug Facebook, FB displays that the name and profile picture is required.  I have not specified profile picture in my policy.  What am i missing?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bkau.png) is a screenshot of what I see on FB

Below is the a snippet of my facebook configuration in my custom policy

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Sign in with Facebook</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
          <DisplayName>Sign in with Facebook</DisplayName>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">{Settings:FacebookAppId}</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email public_profile</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,email</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: Can someone please steer me in the right direction for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook prompts for consent based on the permissions you selected on the Facebook dev portal for your application. This has nothing to do with your B2C custom policy. You need to adjust the permissions on your application in the Facebook dev portal and remove the permission for profile photo.